# Some DLLs in root of C: drive

Tags: windows, dll, installer

These two files appeared in the root of my C: drive in Windows 11. Does anybody know what created them? What is their purpose and why are they in root?

- `appverifUI.dll`
- `vfcompat.dll`

Comment: appverifUI.dll is [Application Verifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/application-verifier) and it’s a legitimate application, vfcompat.DLL likely is connected to it. As for location, it was probably installed to that location, by a user

Comment: Are there also a bunch of .txt files like readme.txt? Some older MSVC Runtime installers used to accidentally extract their temporary files into C:\ directly and then failed to clean them up after installation.

Comment: No, just two dlls. [link](https://pasteboard.co/QKsrXcGLKNqZ.png)

Comment: Are they signed by Microsoft?

Comment: Yes, but file compare says they are different from c:\Windows\System32\appverifUI.dll and c:\Windows\SysWOW64\appverifUI.dll.

Comment: Today I installed Windows 11 SDK (10.0.22621.0) from Visual Studio Installer v3.4.2246.31370. After that I noticed these two files in C:\. Their sizes are: `appverifUI.dll` = 112,104 bytes, `vfcompat.dll` = 66,176 bytes. Their file version: `appverifUI.dll` = N/A, `vfcompat.dll` = 10.0.22621.755.

Comment: I have them too. Same sizes and signed by Microsoft. I have Visual Studio. I'm guessing some component of it has a buggy installer.

Comment: Your question has an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76300242/8659747

Comment: Yesterday I updated Visual Studio to 17.6.4. After that I noticed these two files in C:\. Their sizes are: `appverifUI.dll` = 112,080 bytes, `vfcompat.dll` = 66,160 bytes. Their file version: `appverifUI.dll` = N/A, `vfcompat.dll` = 10.0.22621.1778. I just deleted them the last time (5 months ago), and didn't notice anything wrong. I deleted them now too.

Answer (score 4):

> Does anybody know what created them?

These files appeared for me after running the [Windows 11 SDK 10.0.22621.1778 installer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-sdk/).

> What is their purpose

From my research in to this, it appears that `appverifUI.dll` (UI Definition) and `vfcompat.dll` (required to run the Compatibility tests) are needed by [Application Verifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/application-verifier) (appver) from Microsoft.

[image]

The test can be enabled through the UI (shown above) or through the command line using:

```
appverif -enable HighVersionLie -for xcopy.exe
```

Replace xcopy.exe with the executable you need to test.

When the application is launched next, these tests are run.  I verified errors in the UI and running Compatibility tests when they are removed.  However, removing the DLLs in the C:\ root folder did not affect the operation of `C:\system32\appverifUI.exe`.

**Duplicate DLLs found in `C:\windows\system32`**

Under `C:\windows\system32` two DLLs with the same name exist, and this lead me to compare the differences under a DLL viewer tool.  I choose [JetBrains dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) (free), and with a little help from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495244/how-can-i-test-a-windows-dll-file-to-determine-if-it-is-32-bit-or-64-bit), I noticed these values under the Machine segment of the File (COFF) header:

[image]

It becomes clear that one is 32-bit (0x014C = i386) and the other is 64-bit (0x8664 = AMD64) versions of the DLL required by `appverif.exe`.  Surprisingly, I also found `appverif.exe` in `C:\SysWOW64`.  Then, I found this in the Application Verifier documentation:

> **Using Application Verifier with WOW64**
>
> You can use either the 32-bit or the 64-bit version of Application Verifier to verify a 32-bit application running under WOW64.

Ironically, it looks like the 32-bit appverif.exe is located in C:\Windows\SysWOW64 (also supported [here](https://Why%20do%2064-bit%20DLLs%20go%20to%20System32%20and%2032-bit%20DLLs%20to%20SysWoW64%20on%2064-bit%20Windows?)).

Following through on my hunch, I tried to run `C:\SysWOW64\appverif.exe` and it ran only through command line.  However, after moving `C:\appverifUI.dll` and `C:\vfcompat.dll` in to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`, I was able to launch the UI and run Compatibility tests.

> why are they in root

At this I can only speculate - I would guess they are some how linked together elsewhere (i.e. by references in the SDK).

However, one thing is clear, if you need to use the 32-bit appverif UI and run the corresponding Compatibility tests, **you should not delete those files**.  But, I can't see why you would need the 32-bit appverif since the 64-bit version works too.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same two files in `C:/`, and they are both 32-bit dlls, and I checked the version of `C:/vfcompat.dll` (10.0.22621.xxx), `C:/Windows/SysWOW64/vfcompat.dll` (10.0.22000.xxx) and `C:/Windows/SysWOW64/appverif.exe` (10.0.22621.xxx).

So I moved the two files to `C:/Windows/SysWOW64/`.